# Sorting array with PHP usort fails

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I created an array with a loop building it kind of like this:

```
$new_array[] = array(
    'rating_value' => (float)$rating_value
);
```

**NEW: I add the long array. It seems to work with short arrays but not with the long one.**

```
        $new_array = array (
     0 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 4.5,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 0,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 4.5,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 3.5,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 3.5,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 3,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 5,
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 2.5,
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 3.5,
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 4.5,
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 0,
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 0,
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 4,
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    'rating_value' => 4,
  ),
);
```

I want to sort it by `rating_value`.

```
usort($new_array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['rating_value'] - $b['rating_value'];
});

print_r( $new_array );
```

Why does this not work? I don't get the numbers in correct order, just sort of random.

I have looked into **many** previous questions on stackoverflow. That is where I got the usort function but still no luck.

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://codepad.viper-7.com/23Emv4

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is the well known int limitation, see duplicate. If that's not it, provide a more compelling test case and demonstrate the results.

Comment: It does not work when more numbers are added. Look here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/hB51Ge

Comment: Thanks @deceze for pointing the correct answer out. It works and it was a limitation with float.